# Bad RIP Value only on kernel 5.3.0-26-generic

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I'm on 19.10 (Eoan Ermine). Recently, I let apt upgrade my kernel from 5.3.0-18-generic to 5.3.0-26-generic.

5.3.0-18-generic continues to work fine in both recovery and regular boot modes. However, 5.3.0-18-generic fails to recover properly from suspend; the system is unresponsive even though the display manager is visible, the keyboard is unresponsive.

If I attempt to boot, however, into 5.3.0-26 from any state, I get this message (only visible using recovery mode):

[image: 5.3.0-26 kernel panic]

5.3.0-18 continues to boot fine using either regular or recovery boot modes.

I do see the line about the syntax error from the suspend file, but I'm inclined to assume that's unrelated to the more serious kernel panic.

Here's lshw:

```
    description: Notebook
    product: 20HRCTO1WW (LENOVO_MT_20HR_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad X1 Carbon 5th)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: ThinkPad X1 Carbon 5th
    serial: PF0ZXXWS
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0.0 dmi-3.0.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=notebook family=ThinkPad X1 Carbon 5th power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_20HR_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad X1 Carbon 5th uuid=4CECD9FC-4E2A-B211-A85C-BED5C2304DEA
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 20HRCTO1WW
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Defined
       serial: L3HF7B600XZ
       slot: Not Available
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 3
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1867 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: K4EBE304EB-EGCF
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1867 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: K4EBE304EB-EGCF
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 7
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 8
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 9
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: a
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz
          serial: None
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2502MHz
          capacity: 3900MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: b
          version: N1MET59W (1.44 )
          date: 11/25/2019
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 620
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:138 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:ec348000-ec348fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:ec320000-ec32ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-18-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: MK730
                   vendor: Cooler Master Technology Inc.
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: 0.10
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.10
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: Integrated Camera
                   vendor: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 0.06
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:3 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   vendor: Validity Sensors, Inc.
                   physical id: 9
                   bus info: usb@1:9
                   version: 1.64
                   serial: 1fb9808954ea
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-18-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:1
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:ec349000-ec349fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:134 memory:ec34a000-ec34afff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 memory:ec200000-ec2fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:127 memory:ec200000-ec200fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:ec100000-ec1fffff
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlp4s0
                version: 88
                serial: b0:35:9f:c3:5e:0b
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-18-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:135 memory:ec100000-ec101fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:ec000000-ec0fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
                vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:ec000000-ec003fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:bc000000-ea0fffff ioport:70000000(size=1241513984)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:ec344000-ec347fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:143 memory:ec340000-ec343fff memory:ec330000-ec33ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:ec34b000-ec34b0ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             logical name: enp0s31f6
             version: 21
             serial: 54:e1:ad:c6:8b:61
             size: 100Mbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.100.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
             resources: irq:128 memory:ec300000-ec31ffff
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 0
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device LEN0071
          physical id: c
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device LEN0072
          physical id: d
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: e
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:09
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: f
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:0a
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 10
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:0b
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 11
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
  *-battery
       product: 01AV430
       vendor: SMP
       physical id: 1
       slot: Front
       capacity: 57020mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.5V
```

Thoughts?